# C# Почему интерфейсы "IEnumerable " и "IEnumerator" реализуются в разных классах?

Tags: c#, интерфейс

Не могу понять для чего целый отдельный класс для реализации интерфейса `IEnumerable`, разве нельзя его реализовать в том же классе что и `IEnumerator`, в этом есть какая-то логика или просто для удобства?

Comment: Не понял если честно про какие интерфейсы речь.

Comment: @tym32167 наверное буква E пропущена

Comment: @iiKuzmychov я было подумал об опечатке, но автор опечатался аж 4 раза. Либо это какие то другие интерфейсы, либо автор зачем то специально искажет их названия по неведомой мне причине.

Comment: Очевидно, потому, что одну коллекцию можно одновременно перечислять несколько раз. И у каждого перечисления своё состояние.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IEnumerable` это **перечислимое**, например массив или список или алгоритм генерации данных, а `IEnumerator` - **перечислитель**, который по этим данным проходит, конечный автомат.

То есть это две большие разницы. Чтобы перечислить перечислимое, нужно запросить у него перечислитель `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()`, а чтобы начать перечислять, нужен цикл, вызывать в нем переход к следующему элементу `IEnumerator.MoveNext()` и обращаться к текущему элементу `IEnumerator.Current`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IEnumerable<int> enumerable = new int[] { 2, 4, 6, 15 };
    IEnumerator<int> enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator();
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current);
    }
    enumerator.Dispose(); // почитайте про IDisposable
}
```

Может ли быть упрощенный вариант, типа перечислитель без перечислимого - может, так как генерацию значений можно написать прямо в классе перечислителя, а вот наоборот - нет. Без `MoveNext()` и `Current` ничего не выйдет.

Почитайте про шаблон проектирования "Конечный автомат" или еще его называют "Машина состояний". Именно на нём работает перечислитель.